# Parallel.ForEach processing and adding in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I want to convert bytes to pdf format. As i want to speed up the process to use Parallel/Multithreading feature.

Problem is it hangs or breaks up when MaxDegreeOfParallelism is more than 1. I guess memory is getting corrupted..Can anyone please advise?

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, Byte[]> letterContentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, Byte[]>();

private void ProcessFilesInParallel()
{
var files = _oldDbContext.LetterData.Where(x => x.ByteContent != null).Select(y => y).Take(100);
Parallel.ForEach(files, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, file =>
{
    byte[] byteCompleteLetterPdf = null;
    byteCompleteLetterPdf = ConvertToPdfWithAspose(file.ByteContent);
    letterContentDictionary.TryAdd(file.LetterId, byteCompleteLetterPdf);
});
}
```

Comment: What error do you see when the parallel loop _breaks up_ ?

Comment: Are you sure your method `ConvertToPdfWithAspose` is thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

Try buffering DbContext results in an array first, like this:

```
var files = _oldDbContext.LetterData.Where(x => x.ByteContent != null).Select(y => y).Take(100).ToArray();
```